# Dell XPS 15z Graphics Freezes, Black Screen, Overheating

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, graphics, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have had Ubuntu running on my Dell XPS 15z for a while. I took troubleshooting to fix overheating by installing Jupiter and TLP.

Graphics errors like scrolling up by two-finger gesture opens and closes the dash quickly until it crashes, these were more of a problem I had run some command I now don't remember to activate my NVIDIA card, which since 13.04, only the Intel one works.

Recently, I installed Compiz Config Manager and enabled unity improvements and they worked flawlessly for a week. Today while playing music and switching a work space, the graphics could not keep up and it crashed. Also when I shut my laptop lid instead of locking the screen, it turned black and never returned.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work be uninstalling Compiz Config Settings Manager, deleting the Ubuntu partitions and installing Ubuntu 13.10, and installing Cpufreq Indicator and setting it to Powersave.